# What happened to Spring Cloud RSocket

Tags: spring-cloud, rsocket

I have a question to the Spring Cloud guys.

Approx. a year ago, there were nice presentations about Spring Cloud RSocket.
Part of it included RSocket Support in Spring Cloud Gateway, aka. the rsocket-broker.

Now I see that https://github.com/spring-cloud-incubator/spring-cloud-rsocket has been archived.

I am wondering: does this mean Spring Cloud RSocket is dead? Is there any replacement? Is there any other support for RSocket in Spring Cloud Gateway? Or is Spring Cloud RSocket simply dormant and there is hope for it to be resurrected?

P.S.: I am aware of RSocket support in Spring Boot which is very nicely described [here](https://github.com/benwilcock/spring-rsocket-demo). What I am interested in, is the Spring Cloud RSocket features that I did not find the Spring Boot RSocket support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the description of that project

This repository is now inactive. Please see https://github.com/rsocket-broker

Comment: Thanks. Great to see that this goes on!